# Run macOS Test Cases on the Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: macos, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

Hi I have an macOS Application which needs to be configured for CI/CD purpose on the Jenkins.

I need to run the test cases before making the application available for the distribution or before creating a package file.

I am using the below mentioned command

```
xcodebuild -workspace xxx.xcworkspace -sdk macosx11.3 -scheme xxx -destination "platform=OS X,arch=x86_64" clean test
```

when I execute this command in the Jenkins it throws me an error

**ERROR: The test runner encountered an error (Failed to establish communication with the test runner. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the result bundle at /Users/ec2-user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-gkolnyonjdnyixfknefsjvbsyzia/Logs/Test/Run-xxx-2021.05.24_11-58-07-+0000.xcresult. (Underlying Error: Couldn’t communicate with a helper application. Try your operation again. If that fails, quit and relaunch the application and try again. The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.testmanagerd.control was invalidated.))**

I need to make use of macOS itself to run as a simulator. As Jenkins runs as a Daemon on the ec-2 instance.

**NOTE**: NOT USING XCODE PLUGIN TO EXECUTE MY COMMANDS

Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My MacOS system was a slave and I was running my scripts through the Linux server.
macOS was connected using the SSH earlier then this authentication method was required to be changed to access the UI of the Mac

Test cases running now

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. What did you change with the authentication?

Comment: Use JNLP method, A jar is required to installed on the mac slave and use it

Comment: @JatinGarg can you give more info here? I'm having the same problem but don't really understand your solution.

Comment: @Hundley Added some notes based on my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Based on observation, macOS Big Sur, Monterey, and probably subsequent versions no longer allow tests to be run through a SSH session. By changing the way Jenkins controller connects to the slave, you can prevent the command from being run through SSH.

The first way, Jenkins built-in, to do this and easiest is to use the JNLP method for agent communication. This will involve running a Jenkins agent on the slave machine that communicates with the Jenkins controller. In the end, the agent on the machine is running the test command rather than through a SSH session.

The second way is to build your own agent. It could be as simple as a file change trigger leading to a script executing. This is only necessary if for some reason the Jenkins slave is not able to connect to the Jenkins controller due to some networking constraints.